# Aux Audio Input for 2006 Honda Accord

Tags: electrical, honda, audio, accord

I'd like to add an auxiliary audio input to my 2006 Honda Accord LX-SE:

1. What parts do I need to purchase?
2. Can someone with a rudimentary understanding of electronics perform the installation?
3. What's involved in installing the parts from (1)?

Answer (score 4):

I just did this on a 2007 Accord SE.

I bought this [adapter](http://a.co/d/9vKJoZg) which plugs into a port in the back of the factory stereo.  To access the port, you have to disassemble a small portion of your car's interior.  [Watch this](http://youtu.be/4yP3YGCtQ_I) for instructions.

---

**Sound quality**

The sound quality is reasonable, but not excellent.  You can hear a subtle but constant background noise when your music is playing at low volumes.  This [ground loop isolator](http://amzn.com/B001EAQTRI) reduces that noise but does not eliminate it.

---

**Bluetooth**

I also took it a step further and added this [aux to bluetooth adapter](http://amzn.com/B009NLTW60).  It has a microphone for phone calls and buttons for controlling music playback.

---

**Overall**

The entire installation took less than 2 hours.  All of the electronics/adapters were just plug-n-play.  Disassembling the dash without damaging/breaking the interior plastics was slightly challenging.  This should work for 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006 and 2007 Accords that *don't* have the navigation package.

Comment: Could you please update the link for the adapter, it is not working anymore.

Comment: @DávidMolnár - updated!

Comment: One thing I don't understand. How are the cables routed outside of the radio compartment?

Answer (score 3):

There is almost certainly a genuine OE option available that you could purchase from a dealer and probably get them to fit as well. This would be worth looking into just so you know how much it would cost, it may not be super expensive, but my gut feel says it will be reasonably costly.

Or there are aftermarket options available. [www.crutchfield.com](http://www.crutchfield.com) has a pretty good web site where you can select the exact model car you are enquiring about and it will list compatible components for you. I entered the info you provided and it came up with an option for a "[HON03-AUX](http://www.crutchfield.com/p_469HON3AUX/P-I-E-Honda-Auxiliary-Input-Adapter.html?tp=422)" for $89USD which plugs in behind your stereo somewhere. Be aware that it does list quite a few caveats about its compatibility (such as "Factory radio must have CD changer controls"), so read carefully before ordering.
Apparently the product comes with an installation guide and apparently Crutchfield offers lifetime tech support so it seems like it should be easily fitted by someone with not too many electronic or automotive skills.
I've never installed one of these, and I have never had anything to do with Crutchfield (I just found the website today) so I'm far from an expert here. But given that the component must be plugged into the back of the radio the skill set required will be more to do with accessing the back of the radio than electronics. You may have to remove part of the dash in order to gain access to the rear of the radio - so be aware of that.